Script that finds country code from a capital city
I want to write the script that transforms
"London" to  "London,uk"
"Barcelona" to "Barcelona,es"

I have a list of a cities and want to get the code of a country to then append it.
I tried:
import pycountry

capital = input("Capital city ")

country_code = None

for country in pycountry.countries:
    try:
        capital_name = country.capital
        if capital_name and capital_name.lower() == capital.lower():
            country_code = country.alpha_2
            break
    except AttributeError:
        continue

but it doesn't work.

What does "it doesnt work" mean? What happens? What do you want to happen instead?

doesnt return a country code

Why do you think pycountry country objects have .capital attribute?

Will the cities always be capital cities? In your example you have Barcelona, which is not the capital city of Spain.

uk is not an ISO country abbreviation. It's gb. So you may struggle to do this unless you can find a module that doesn't work with ISO abbreviations. You also need to bear in mind that when you look up a city name such as London, there's more than one London in the world (albeit that they're not all capital cities so identifying a capital city as opposed to any other kind of city is going to be an additional challenge for you)

This dataset does not even have a "capital" field in it. So, you will get AttributeError every time!
EDIT:
So, you need to convert the capital to country then search the dataset by names in it. There are lots of datasets to do this like this.
Then use this code to find the code of the country
for country in pycountry.countries:
    name = country.name
    if name.lower() == country_name.lower():
        country_code = country.alpha_2
        break

Or you can use another library.

Thank you for posting an answer. While it may be correct, it would be more helpful if you pointed OP to a way to accomplish what they intend to do.

@Friedrich you are right i updated my answer

You can use the geograpy3 package, e.g., after installing with
pip install geograpy3

you can do
import geograpy

city = input("Enter city: ")

locate = geograpy.locateCity(city)

if locate:
    country = locate.country.iso
    print(f"{city}, {country}")
else:
    print(f"Could not locate city: '{city}'")

Note, that this will just return a single city in cases where there are multiple cities with the same name, and it may not be the one you want!
Another package you could try is geonamescache.

The dataset pycountry has for ISO 3166-1 does not have any information about capitals, so your code will result in an error. Instead of looping over each country you can query its subdivisions directly:
import pycountry

capital = input("Capital city ")
country_code = None

subdivisions = pycountry.subdivisions.search_fuzzy(capital)
if subdivisions:
    country_code = subdivisions[0].country_code

Note that there is a caveat here that we are simply taking the first matching subdivision found in the dataset, this might actually not be a Capital city or the capital city the user actually wants. The subdivisions dataset does have a type field so you can try to filter it out a bit more if you want but it doesn't seem to cover much of the data about capitals and there seem to be only 4 instances of "Capital city".

Using Internet connection
Try using openwheatermap geocoding API to get the country of a city.
http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=London&limit=1&appid=yourapikey

Response:
{
    "name": "London",
    "local_names": {"contry1": "name", "contry2": "name"},
    "lat": 51.5073219,
    "lon": -0.1276474,
    "country": "GB",
    "state": "England"
}

The "country" key is what you want.
import requests


api_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct'
params = {
    'q': '',
    'limit': 1,
    'appid': 'yourapikey'
}

capital = input('Capital city: ')
params['q'] = capital

galinha = requests.get(url=api_url, params=params)
country_code = galinha.json()[0]['country']

cachorro = capital + ',' + country_code.lower()

print(cachorro)


